# Termination point at main panel for a 4 wire feeder ground wire to sub-panel in detached structure

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

I plan to upgrade an older 40 amp 3 wire feeder to my shop to a safer 4 wire feeder. No issues at all running a #6 solid copper in existing  conduit to an un-bonded ground bus-bar in the sub-panel. Problem I have is the Main load center for the house is mounted inside a room in the center of the house, making it not so easy to rout the ground wire from sub-panel into the main panel.

Question I have: would code allow me to connect the feeder ground wire from the detached shop sub-panel to the ufer plate for the Main Panel ? Seems this would be OK since the main panel has the bonded ground/neutral bus-bar. Thanks

Comment: Wait, are the 3 conductors in conduit the whole way?  Is the conduit metal and non-flexible?  Is it rigid/IMC (that is, threaded)? Or is it all indoors?

Comment: 3 wires, 35 feet run, under ground,  2.5" PVC type conduit, Jay box at shop and house, Sub-panel has disconnect and two ground rods already in place.

Comment: Have you thought about pulling out the three  wires, adding the fourth and repulling the whole bunch?  You've probably got 3#8 so a #6 would be over kill (I mean over grounded).  4 wires in a 2.5" conduit for 35" totally doable in my humble opinion.

Comment: House and shop built in 1979, The three conductors currently in the 2.5" PVC are #4 Aluminum, The main Breaker is 2 pole 40 amp, plenty sufficient for what I do. There were phone and intercom wires in the conduit also which I pulled out very easily (did not need). Seems like a little over kill for 40 amp circuit. I have considered using old conductors as pullers and pull in 4 New THWN 4 wires. (#8). The old aluminum wires have no visible markings on the sheathing, may not have  been correct even back in '79!  4 new copper #8's really make sense !

Comment: What size is the panel in the garage?

Comment: 200 AMP Main Service Panel

Comment: What about the sub panel?

Comment: Sub Panel is 50 Amp

Comment: #4 AL is good for 55 amp, 65 if the 75 degree C  applies.  Don't be in a hurry to scrap the AL as it preforms well in this case.

Comment: Can’t use 75 because under 100 amp / #1 wire requires 60 deg table per 110.14.C.1.A

Comment: OK, Thanks for info, think i'll just add the ground wire needed for the 4 wire feeder.

Comment: @EdBeal  I remember that from one of your posts yesterday. I was waiting for the sub panel size.

Comment: Current code would allow for a ground to be pulled from a ground that is from the same panel.  If you have a large enough one closer #8 , probably not.  if the original grounding electrode conductor is available and easy access I would run a #6 not much difference and any future upgrades would be covered from that to the conduit and to the panel. Any splice into the grounding electrode conductor needs to be done with listed irreversible pressure connectors (or exothermic welding) then run that would be code compliant

Comment: The Current Stranded bare cable going from Main House Panel to Uffer plate is .251" outside diameter, I am assuming #6 ? I will research the irreversible pressure connector, I want all to meet code requirments, Thanks for your help

Comment: @EdBeal -- not if the terminations at both ends are 75degC rated (which panel and breaker terms have been for ages now)

Comment: I agree if all the components are listed for 75 that table can be used, in my state testing if not identified as such that section of code is used. +

Answer (score 1):

Definitely separate out that neutral and ground wire.

### Don't bother replacing the aluminum wires

Yeah I know there's some ooga-booga out there about aluminum, but that has nothing to do with your heavy feeder, which is fine stuff and you should keep it. The problem related to very small wires in 15/20A branch circuits, specifically use of outlets and switches whose lugs were rated copper-only, and under political pressure, *UL hastily cross-rated them for aluminum* without proper testing.  Aluminum lugs are the universal donor, they cheerfully take Al or Cu wire. Hence many panels use Al lugs, correctly and without difficulty.

So all you need for the care and feeding of Al feeder is to keep it clean and use the anti-ox goop.  If you're splicing that somewhere, use insulated Polaris lug splices just big enough for the larger wire; much nicer than using bare splices and wrapping them with globs of electrical tape. *The Polaris bars are made of aluminum*.

Your #4 Al wire is capable of being fed from a 60A supply breaker.  That is also limited by other segments of cable/wire, as well as the subpanel's bus ampacity if it doesn't have a main breaker of its own.

An outbuilding requires a disconnect switch; 95% of the time you get that by choosing a panel with a main breaker.  That breaker size does not matter for its role as a disconnect switch. You can never count on the convenience of the local "main" tripping first, however, with a 40A "local main" and a 60A feed, it might just work!

Anyway, I'd hold onto that nice ampacity of the aluminum.  I know you've got your plans figured out, but honestly, the world is too full of surprises to ever say that for sure. Whoever guessed they'd work the bugs out of electric cars, for instance.

### Retrofitting ground

So yeah. Just pull a #10 Cu ground wire through the conduit, add a separate ground bar to the panel, pull any N-G bonds, and you're all set.

It's a shame you didn't pull the ground wire in (or at least a pulling string) when you pulled the phone/intercom out.  Of course the phone and intercom were completely illegal; you can't put signal wires in the same pipe as mains power.

I wouldn't grab the Ufer ground, but I'd grab the copper wire going right to it.

Generally you can take a retrofit ground back to any of these:

- The panel that serves the load
- Metal conduit that goes back to that panel, if the metal conduit is rated for carrying grounds (all non-flexible and some flexible conduit is).
- Any junction box visited by a branch circuit coming out of that panel, which has a sufficiently large ground wire (any >=30A circuit must have a #10 ground wire, so that would suffice).
- Anywhere along the Grounding Electrode System; i.e. the run from the service panel to the grounding rods/pipe/Ufer.

Comment: Thank you for the info, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that would be OK. But to bring your sub-panel up to code you'll need 2 ground rods for your detached building as well.

Comment: Yes the shop already has the two ground rods and a disconnect for conductors at sub-panel entry